# Exporting with Local Coordinates / Pivot Points

Tags: export, webgl

When exporting in Blender, it seems as though all objects are represented in world space.

I wish to have each object represented in their own local space relative to their own pivot point. With an associated transform from their parent.

Is this not possible? It makes it infinitely easier to use in other applications.

I'm not fussed which export I use, as I then use assimp2json to convert it to a JSON file and load it into a WebGL application. The problem being that when I rotate one of my meshes, it rotates around the world origin instead of the pivot point of the mesh.

Comment: This isn't exactly what you are asking for, but you could set the object's rotation and location to zero on all axes before exporting, this effectively sets the local rotation to global.

Comment: But then it would not keep the model hierarchy no? I wish objects to be relative to each other, but they should be in local space, the format should contain the respective transforms to go from local space to world space.